# Multiple Distinct Shattered Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is html code for content within Shattered Popup:

```
 <div class="popups-cont">
    <div class="popups-cont__overlay"></div>
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="popup__pieces"></div>
        <div class="popup__content">
            <div class="popup__close"></div>
            <p class="popup__text">1111111</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="popups-cont">
    <div class="popups-cont__overlay"></div>
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="popup__pieces"></div>
        <div class="popup__content">
            <div class="popup__close"></div>
            <p class="popup__text">2222222</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <img id="c1" class="client col1 row1" src="http://bower.io/img/bower-logo.png" alt="">
<img id="c2" class="client col2 row1" src="https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png" alt="">
```

When clicking on button with id **c1** I expect modals with **popup__text  = "1"** to open and **"2"** when **c2** is clicked.
Javascript code:

```
var numOfPieces = 6*6;
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
function insertInnerPieces($el, innerPieces) {
    for (var i = 0; i < innerPieces; i++) {
        var $inner = document.createElement('div');
        $inner.classList.add('popup__piece-inner');
        $el.appendChild($inner);
    }
};
for (var i = 1; i <= numOfPieces; i++) {
    var $piece = document.createElement('div');
    $piece.classList.add('popup__piece');

    insertInnerPieces($piece, 3);
    frag.appendChild($piece);
}
document.querySelector('.popup__pieces').appendChild(frag);
var $popupsCont = document.querySelector('.popups-cont');
var $popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
var popupAT = 900;

document.querySelector('#c1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    $popupsCont.classList.add('s--popup-active');
    $popup.classList.add('s--active');
});
document.querySelector('#c2').addEventListener('click', function() {
    $popupsCont.classList.add('s--popup-active');
    $popup.classList.add('s--active');
});
function closeHandler() {
    $popupsCont.classList.remove('s--popup-active');
    $popup.classList.remove('s--active');
    $popup.classList.add('s--closed');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $popup.classList.remove('s--closed');
    }, popupAT);
}
document.querySelector('.popup__close').addEventListener('click', closeHandler);
document.querySelector('.popups-cont__overlay').addEventListener('click', closeHandler);
```

How do I get distinct modals to pop up from respective icons/buttons?

You can find the fiddle example here:  [Shattered Popup Example](https://jsfiddle.net/PHI_VIZ/mpsfmgz0/)

Comment: Fiddle link is not working..!